# Custom OWIN authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I'm trying to roll my own authentication for MVC5 using OWIN. I'd like to avoid the standard .NET identity + EF stuff as I'm re-writing the web layer of an existing website and leaving the underlying DB intact (which used a custom forms auth provider, bcrypt for passwords, etc.). I'm having trouble getting my users authenticated at the moment. Here's what I currently have:

Startup.cs:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login")
        });
    }
}
```

AccountController.cs:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager
    {
        get
        {
            return this.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        }
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View();

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.Email));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, model.Email));

        this.authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = model.RememberMe }, identity);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        this.authenticationManager.SignOut();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

Now, my Home/Index action is decorated with an `[Authorize]` attribute. This seems to work as when I navigate to that page, I get pushed to the login page. This correctly posts back and calls the `IAuthenticationManager.SignIn` method, then redirects me to the home page. However, at this point, I am simply redirected back to the login page again, suggesting that my user isn't actually signed in yet. I've written my own WebAPI auth handlers (API key auth in the header, etc.) and they are custom middleware but a lot of info on the net suggests the below is sufficient for auth in MVC. Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

No sooner had I written this, I instantly spotted the problem: my authentication type was different in my OWIN startup class and my account controller. Changed to be the same, works perfectly.

Comment: Any tutorial can I look up onto when I would like to write my custom owin implementation?